# SQL Subquery IN SELECT [Symfony3]

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, createquery

I Have Table Actions with the following fields :

- idAction
- Cloture
- Date

I'd Like to loop through and display a list of all `idAction` In my DB + `idAction` with `Cloture = 0` Group By the same Date (both of them).

I tried below method. But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(

'SELECT COUNT(a.idAction) AS nmbreAction , week(a.dateOuverture) AS week,( SELECT COUNT(c.idAction) , week(c.dateOuverture) FROM ActionActionBundle:Action c 
WHERE c.cloture = 0 ) AS nmbreRetard FROM ActionActionBundle:Action a 
GROUP BY week');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, you question lacks a lot of information. Is this what you need?

```
SELECT COUNT(a.idAction) AS nmbreAction ,
       week(a.dateOuverture) AS week,
       (SELECT COUNT(c.idAction) 
        FROM ActionActionBundle:Action c
        WHERE c.cloture = 0 
          and week(c.dateOuverture) = week(a.dateOuverture)) AS nmbreRetard 
FROM ActionActionBundle:Action a
GROUP BY week(a.dateOuverture)
```

You can't select more than 1 column in a sub query\correlated query in the select list, which was probably showed to you in the error message.

**EDIT:** Better of do that:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.idAction) AS nmbreAction ,
       week(a.dateOuverture) AS week,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a.cloture = 0 THEN 1 END) as nmbreRetard
FROM ActionActionBundle:Action a
GROUP BY week(a.dateOuverture)
```

Comment: Exactly SAGI :D Thank you So Much

Comment: @M.Mery No problem. Look at the edit, a better and more efficient way to do this. No need for this extra select .